# How can I get textid + 5 value?

Tags: android, textview

I used following code in my main activity for android app but username value is only 5. How can I get textid + 5 value? Please help me. How can I do it?

```
TextView username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textid);
username.setText("" + 5);
```

Comment: What do you want to do actually? Please explain little more.

Comment: Calculate for textview value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
username.setText(username.getText().toString() + 5);
```

Comment: Because the + in this answer is interpreted as String concatination, so "5"+5 will be "55", "monkey" + 5 will be "monkey5". You can not (in Java) multiply "monkey" by 10, so also not "5" by 10. You'll have to convert "5" (as String) to 5 (as number), then you can multiply 5 by 10 (=50).

Comment: username.setText(Integer.parseInt(username.getText().toString()) * 10);   is that what you want?